# How to get a html file preview in iframe by using input file type in javascript (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, input, input-type-file

Currently I am creating a web page to edit HTML content. So, the user has to load html file in `<iframe>` by using `<input type="file">`. Here the problem is I don't know how to get value of `<input>`. Can any one help me in this regards

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ this link may be usefull to you

Comment: +1 @Thirumalaimurugan, but this is not supported in IE9/8, which is still kinda popular, sadly.

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis Thank you, IE is the worst browser, I don't know why they are in the market to make the HTML developer struggle any way currently they are vanishing from the market slowly